# SQL Pivot with just two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to do a PIVOT on a table with two rows like this:

```
Category       |   Sector
---------------------------
Bulbs          |   DIY
Bulbs          |   Home
Picnic blanket |   DIY
Picnic blanket |   Home
Picnic blanket |   Interior
```

Each category can have 1 or more sectors.

I'm trying to get a table like this:

```
Category       | Sector 1  | Sector 2  | Sector 3
-------------------------------------------------
Bulbs          | DIY       | Home      | NULL
Picnic blanket | DIY       | Home      | Interior
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    dbo.fn_DbContent_GetTranslation(pt.Name_DbContentId, 2) 'Category'
    , dbo.fn_DbContent_GetTranslation(s.Name_DbContentId, 2) 'Sector'
FROM dbo.ProductType pt
JOIN dbo.ProductTypeMandator ptm ON ptm.ProductTypeId = pt.Id
JOIN dbo.ProductTypeMandator2PortalSector ptmps ON ptmps.ProductTypeMandatorId = ptm.Id
JOIN dbo.PortalSector ps ON ps.Id = ptmps.PortalSectorId
JOIN dbo.Sector s ON s.Id = ps.SectorId
WHERE
    ptmps.PortalSectorId IN (21, 18, 19)
```

I already did a PIVOT but with a table containing three columns where one contained the values for the headers in the pivot table. In this case the values for the header are missing so I don't know how to do it then.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of sectors and/or the number that you want to show? Any individual query has a fixed "shape" (the number of columns, their names and data types) so if you need to support an unlimited number, you're looking at dynamic SQL to construct the query.

Comment: How did you got that order `sector 1,sector 2..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it that way:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #cats(category nvarchar(25), sector nvarchar(25))

INSERT INTO #cats(category, sector)
VALUES  (N'Bulbs',N'DIY'),
        (N'Bulbs',N'Home'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'DIY'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'Home'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'Interior')

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT category, sector
    FROM #cats
) as dat
PIVOT(
    MAX(sector)
    FOR sector IN([DIY],[Home],[Interior])
) as pvt

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #cats
```

If you want it to be named correctly as in your example, you can combine it with a named numbering:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #cats(category nvarchar(25), sector nvarchar(25))

INSERT INTO #cats(category, sector)
VALUES  (N'Bulbs',N'DIY'),
        (N'Bulbs',N'Home'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'DIY'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'Home'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'Interior')

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT category, sector, N'Sector '+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sector)) as rn
    FROM #cats
) as dat
PIVOT(
    MAX(sector)
    FOR rn IN([Sector 1],[Sector 2],[Sector 3])
) as pvt

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #cats
```

And last but not least, if you want it to be dynamical:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #cats(category nvarchar(25), sector nvarchar(25))

INSERT INTO #cats(category, sector)
VALUES  (N'Bulbs',N'DIY'),
        (N'Bulbs',N'Home'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'DIY'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'Home'),
        (N'Picnic blanket',N'Interior')

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @cols nvarchar(max)

-- get proper column list
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + N',[' + grCols.rn + N']',N'[' + grCols.rn + N']')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT N'Sector '+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sector)) as rn
    FROM #cats
) as grCols

SET @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT category, sector, N''Sector ''+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sector)) as rn
    FROM #cats
) as dat
PIVOT(
    MAX(sector)
    FOR rn IN('+@cols+')
) as pvt'
EXEC(@sql)

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #cats
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways,

One is `Conditional Aggregate`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                rn=Row_number()
                     OVER(
                       partition BY category
                       ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT category,
       [sector 1] = Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN sector END),
       [sector 2] = Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN sector END),
       [sector 3] = Max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN sector END)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY category
```

Another way is using `Pivot`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               sector_col = 'sector '
                            + Cast(Row_number()OVER(partition BY category ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(20))
        FROM   yourtable) A
       PIVOT (Max(sector)
             FOR sector_col IN ([sector 1],
                                [sector 2],
                                [sector 3])) piv
```

**Note :** As mentioned in comments if the `sector` values are not `static` or `unknown` then you may have convert the same to `dynamic query`